# Why include paths are inherited even for private linking

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I have simple project consisting of 2 "libraries" `a` and `b` and executable `c`. I set include path for library `a` (PUBLIC) to `X` (for testing purposes, there's actually no such path).
Now, `b` links privately with `a` and `c` links with `b`. I expect X not to be in include path when compiling `c.cpp` because "it should not know about `a` since it's in private in `b`" But apparently It's here.

So my question is it intended behaviour or not and why.

My code:

a.cpp

```
void a() {}
```

b.cpp

```
void b() {}
```

c.cpp

```
int main() {}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_library(a a.cpp)
target_include_directories(a PUBLIC X)

add_library(b b.cpp)
target_link_libraries(b PRIVATE a)

add_executable(c c.cpp)
target_link_libraries(c PUBLIC b)
```

(Verbose) Compilation log:

```
 /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -H/Users/alexeyd/test/dir -B/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 c
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -H/Users/alexeyd/test/dir -B/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles 6
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CMakeFiles/c.dir/all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/a.dir/depend
cd /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/alexeyd/test/dir /Users/alexeyd/test/dir /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/a.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/a.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/a.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/a.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/a.dir/build
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.dir/a.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -I/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/X   -o CMakeFiles/a.dir/a.cpp.o -c /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/a.cpp
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library liba.a
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/a.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/a.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar qc liba.a  CMakeFiles/a.dir/a.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib liba.a
[ 33%] Built target a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/b.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/b.dir/depend
cd /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/alexeyd/test/dir /Users/alexeyd/test/dir /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/b.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/b.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/b.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/b.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target b
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/b.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/b.dir/build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -I/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/X   -o CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.cpp.o -c /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/b.cpp
[ 66%] Linking CXX static library libb.a
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/b.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/b.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ar qc libb.a  CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib libb.a
[ 66%] Built target b
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/c.dir/depend
cd /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/alexeyd/test/dir /Users/alexeyd/test/dir /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/c.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/c.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/c.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles/c.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target c
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/c.dir/build
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/c.dir/c.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -I/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/X   -o CMakeFiles/c.dir/c.cpp.o -c /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/c.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable c
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/c.dir/c.cpp.o  -o c libb.a liba.a
[100%] Built target c
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

Interesting part of log:

```
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/c.dir/c.cpp.o 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++   -I/Users/alexeyd/test/dir/X   -o CMakeFiles/c.dir/c.cpp.o -c /Users/alexeyd/test/dir/c.cpp
```

I use CMake 3.8.1

Comment: Side note: Remember that there are two distinct phases in play; compilation and linking. Include paths are only relevant during compilation (to find header files), not during linking. When linking, a different set of paths are used to search for the object files/libraries to link. For gcc, this is the difference between the [-I and -L](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) options.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not sure how that matters here. This is primarily a CMake question. `target_link_libraries` doesn't interface only with the linker; it lets you link CMake targets together (which sets up include directories and everything else as well)

Comment: What also surprises me here is that the include path is still present if `b` is linked to `c` privately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strange behavior does not appear if you specify a minimum CMake version >= 2.8.12:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
```

`target_include_directories` and the `PRIVATE`/`PUBLIC` differentiation did not exist before CMake 2.8.12. My take is that with versions older than that CMake chooses to make everything `PUBLIC` by default.

Comment: I would even say it's reasonable to specify `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)` nowadays

Comment: didn't expect that smth depends on minimum_required version as opposite to version I use